# unable to connect to open fire from android

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Android application returns error while creating connection with Open Fire while it works fine at my local server.

> 10-07 14:58:32.347 26785-27124/com.testing.online_soping_app E/XMPPChatDemoActivity: Could not connect to http://demo.vaidiksolutions.in:5222.: remote-server-timeout(504) Could not connect to https://demo.vaidiksolutions.in:5222.
>                                                                                          -- caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: http://demo.vaidiksolutions.in
>   10-07 14:58:32.347 26785-27124/com.testing.online_soping_app E/XMPPChatDemoActivity: Failed to log in as mohit
>   10-07 14:58:32.347 26785-27124/com.testing.online_soping_app E/XMPPChatDemoActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like DNS failed to resolve this domain. Have you tried to ping the server domain?
If the ping is OK, you may try to connect using IP directly.